# When calling the Bootstrap Material date picker, just a whitespace pop-up is displayed

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I was using the bootstrap Material Date Picker when I encountered an issue where only empty pop-ups were displayed with no elements when the Date Picker was called.

[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeYkp.png)

But I'm hoping for the year-month-time and the state where the calendar is displayed.

In this state, none of the datePicker's options have affected the pop-up,
and when i force it remove the "hidden" class in the developer tool,
only the form will appear odd and will not work at all.

I've tried running all the viable methods in bootstrap MaterialDatePicker, but this hasn't affected it.

Is there a way to modify this code to show the full datepicker that shows the date and calendar?

Below is the code and html I used to call the pop-up.
Please understand that English sentences are not fluent because I use a translator.

html :

```
  <script src="/js/plugin/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/plugin/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/plugin/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/plugin/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="edit_tool tool_date">
      <img src="img/m_icon/ico_point.svg" alt="" class="ico_essential">
      <div class="tool_item date_pick">
        <div class="dateText" style="width:100%; height:100%; display: inline-flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="datePicker" class="form-control entrance">
      </div>
    </div>
```

"bootstrap Material Date Picker" call :

```
    $(edit_tool.tool_date).on("click", function() {
      let datePicker = $(this).find("input[name=datePicker]");
      let datePickerKey = $(datePicker).data("dtp");

      if (!datePickerKey) {
        $(datePicker).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0, time: false });
        $(datePicker).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker("setDate", moment());
      }

      $(datePicker).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker("show");
    });
```